Trying to set a keyboard shortcut to the fish shell desktop application
How can one open the fish terminal with a keyboard shortcut like ctl-alt-t in the gnome desktop environment running on debian?
Steps I have taken:

Installed the fish shell and run it from gnome-terminal.
Successfully run the fish shell terminal gui from the applications list in settings>applications.
Checked the fish.desktop file in /usr/share/applications to find the exec command

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
# This file is for use in appimages, which rewrite the path.
# Other uses would have to replace these with the correct path.
Exec=fish
Name=fish
Comment=The user-friendly command line shell
Icon=fish
# "Shell" would be the proper category, but it's reserved so we can't use it.
Categories=ConsoleOnly;System;


Created a keyboard shortcut under Settings>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcuts>View And Customize Shortcuts>Custom Shortcuts>Set Custom Shortcut


But pressing ctl-alt-t doesn't open the fish terminal.

The problem is fish doesn't provide a terminal, it's just a shell environment. You'll have to use something like:
xterm -fg white -bg black -e fish

If you install xterm, and you use that command for the shortcut, it should work as expected.  I don't have gnome-terminal, so I'm not sure if it has an execute option, but it likely does.

Yes, gnome-terminal uses the same option, so  gnome-terminal -e fish would be the command that OP should use.

Any idea how the application (as defined in the fish.desktop file) works then? Does Terminal=true just append -e <exec value> to the default terminal?

@SvenVoigt I don't think it will launch a terminal for the command, or will it?  It must be a .desktop feature if so.  You could use Exec=gnome-terminal -e fish in the same way, and I bet it would work with Terminal=false
